# Filename not printing correctly with underscore "_" in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am using this

```
DATE_FOLDER=$(date +"%b-%d-%a-%G")
FILENAME="HOME_$date1.tar.gz"

echo $BACKUP_DESTINATION/$DATE_FOLDER/$FOLDERNAME_$FILENAME
```

My output is

```
home/May-04-Wed-2011/HOME_May-04-0718PM-2011.tar.gz
```

but if I use  `-` instead of underscore `_`

```
echo $BACKUP_DESTINATION/$DATE_FOLDER/$FOLDERNAME-$FILENAME
```

then my ouput is correct

```
/home/May-04-Wed-2011/vmware-HOME_May-04-0717PM-2011.tar.gz
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`_` is a valid character for a variable name, and `$FOLDERNAME_` doesn't exist.

```
echo "$BACKUP_DESTINATION/$DATE_FOLDER/${FOLDERNAME}_$FILENAME"
```

Comment: thanks , i didn't notice that

Answer (score -3):

The problem is here : `HOME_$date1.tar.gz`
and also here: `_$FILENAME`.
If you use `_$` then the `$` is escaped.

Nevertheless you can do it with: `\\_$`.
Then you escape the `_` with the `\` and the `$` will be interpreted as you are used to it.

Comment: The proposed solution actually happens to work but the explanation is a load of manure. -1